# unrecognized character when creating mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to create a service for mongodb in window 7. When it enter

```
mongod  --config c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --install
```

i get this error

> error command line: unrecognized line in ' ■l'

mongod.cfg

```
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
```

Comment: looks like you have the same issue as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/FOn6ObvlkNw)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As jimoleary suggested in a comment link, be sure the config file is encoded as ANSI or UTF-8 rather than UTF-16 (Unicode).